# how to view a phabricator commit with local tools

Tags: git, phabricator

We are working with phabricator and git.

Let's say a colleague creates a commit and published it for review with arc-diff, but I don't want to look at it with the web interface, I want to look at it with my local tools.  For the sake of argument using "git difftool -d".

In theory all I would need is for phabricator or arc to give me two commits to run git difftool on.

Is there any way for me to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `arc patch` to land his diff on a new branch or `arc patch --nobranch` to land it on your current branch.  You can then use any tool to process them as git changes.

Comment: Though, you won't be able to leave comments this way.